# UITableView cell.textLabel.text stopped updating after IOS 11 Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Everything was working fine under IOS 10.x

I have a table in the app that is supposed to scan for available BLE devices and present each device in a cell.

When user taps on a cell, it should update the textLabel.text property to say "Please wait...". After it connects, it should call the tableView.reload data() method and cells should list the device names. If the state of a device is connected, it should say connected.

After updating to IOS 11, everything seems to be working, but I am unable to update the text in the cell to indicate "connected." It stays displaying the "please wait" message from when the cell was tapped.

View controller class definition...

```
class BeanConnect: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, PTDBeanManagerDelegate, PTDBeanDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

let beanList=BeanList()
var beanManager: PTDBeanManager?
var waitingToConnect: PTDBean?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableView.delegate=self
    tableView.dataSource=beanList
    beanManager = PTDBeanManager()
    beanManager!.delegate = self
    //tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Here is where I update the textLabel when the cell is touched. This works fine.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text=beanList.items[indexPath.row].name + " Please wait..."
    if (myBean != nil && myBean?.state==PTDBleDeviceState.connectedAndValidated) {
        let waitingBean=beanList.items[indexPath.row]
        self.waitingToConnect=waitingBean
        var e: NSErrorPointer

        print("*******now disconnecting from bean********")

        beanManager?.disconnect(fromAllBeans: e)

    }else {
        myBean=beanList.items[indexPath.row]
        connectToBean(bean: myBean!)
    }

}
```

Here is the part (in a separate module) where the cells are updated. Note that the debug lines indicate that "ConnectedandValidated" is getting triggered. everything seems to work EXCEPT the damn label isn't updating.

```
extension BeanList: UITableViewDataSource {
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let item=items[indexPath.row]
    print("debug code building the table")
    switch item.state {
    case PTDBleDeviceState.attemptingConnection:
        cell.textLabel!.text=item.name + " Connecting..."
        print("debug code attemptingConnection")

    case PTDBleDeviceState.attemptingValidation:
        cell.textLabel!.text=item.name + " Validating..."
        print("debug code attemptingValidation")

    case PTDBleDeviceState.connectedAndValidated:
        cell.textLabel!.text=item.name + " Connected!"
        print("debug code Connected")
        print(item.name + " Connected!")

    default:
        cell.textLabel!.text=item.name
        print("debug code default case")

    }

    return cell

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Tx

Comment: You should not dequeue new cell in "didSelect". Use tableView.cellForRow and get existing cell.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.  If you want to post that as an answer, I will mark it correct.  Weird that IOS 10 let me get away with it.  Thanks Much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not dequeue new cell in "didSelect". Use tableView.cellForRow and get existing cell.